# How to edit the results of a PostGIS layers after executing SQL query in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing

Just getting started with QGIS/PostGIS for a project that involves thousands of points from geo-tagged photos. I'd like to be able to parse a selection of these based on SQL queries but it seems that after querying a PostGIS layer, the editing capabilities are frozen. I assume there must be someway that doesn't involve creating another layer and then updating the original layer.

Comment: What do you mean by parse? Are you creating Query Layers and try to edit them?

Comment: Hi, sorry if I poorly phrased it, I just meant that I want to be able to make a sub-selection from the layer based on an sql statement, then make edits to those records on the layer. When I make a selection on the layer, the editing capabilites are greyed out. Is this something I have to do within QGIS on the attribute table, rather than on the Postgis layer? I find the QGIS selection options very clunky.

Comment: use the filter the create your subset.  Right click on the layer in the TOC, and click Filter.  Then put in your query there.  Then start editing.  If that isn't working you need to add a primary key on your table in postgis.  Like BERA said, you can't edit a query layer or temporary layer.